# How to import data about edge width, node size and colour from CSV file into Cytoscape?

Tags: networkx, cytoscape

I am working with Cytoscape and have a CSV file containing information about nodes and edges in my network. Specifically, the file includes data on the two nodes that are connected, as well as information about node size, color, edge width, and other custom properties.

I would like to import this data into Cytoscape and create a network visualization with nodes that have these custom properties. However, I'm not sure how to do this.

Can someone please advise on how to import CSV data into Cytoscape and display nodes with custom properties?

Answer (score 1):

The manual and tutorial goes over importing tabular data:
https://manual.cytoscape.org/en/stable/Creating_Networks.html#import-networks-from-unformatted-table-files
https://cytoscape.org/cytoscape-tutorials/protocols/importing-network-from-table/#/

For styling take a look at the styling section of the manual:
https://manual.cytoscape.org/en/stable/Styles.html#

And this tutorial:
https://cytoscape.org/cytoscape-tutorials/protocols/basic-data-visualization